# Where to find protobuf.jar for using Google protocol buffers in Java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I downloaded protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz, extracted it, did the usual ./configure, make,  make check, and make install.  However, the file protobuf.jar which seems to be needed for using protocol buffers in Java does not seem to be part of what I downloaded.  Worse, I cannot find this file anywhere.  Please advise me how to proceed.

Comment: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java

Answer (score 27):

You can add it as a Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

All dependency information is available at [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.protobuf%7Cprotobuf-java%7C2.5.0%7Cbundle), or just [download](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar) the .jar file directly.

Comment: I assume this is the non-LITE version of the jar file. Is there somewhere I can download the LITE version from?

Comment: [direct download for 2.6.1](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.6.1/protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar)

Comment: Upvote for downloading directly. Not everybody wants to install maven, edit XML, or see a hundred lines of warnings that result from invoking `mvn package` when the JAR is available for download.

Comment: Are Google's official these JARs in Maven Central?

Comment: See all the versions in Maven Central via this link, latest as of today is 3.4.0:  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java

Answer (score 9):

To generate the `protobuf.jar` file, you need to do what Bruce Martin suggests, but you then need to do the following:

1. Navigate into the `src/main/java/com/google/protobuf` directory
2. Make a directory called `bin`
3. Run the following command to build the `.java` files: `$ javac -d bin *.java`
4. Navigate into the `bin` directory, and finally, run the following command to generate the `protobuf.jar` file: `$ jar cvf protobuf.jar com/`

Then, copy and paste the jar to wherever you need it.

Answer (score 9):

You can download `ProtoBuf Jar` from

[Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.4.1)

then you can put `jar` inside `libs` folder

and if want to get `Protobuf` repository from `maven` then 
add inside `pom.xml` file.

Hope it will help..

Answer (score 7):

The simple solution is that you should compile the jar by yourself.

1. Download the src code from https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list
2. Unzip it and follow the instruction in README

Here is what you should do in Linux

```
./configure  
./make
```

You can install the protoc by run ./make install

Then you need the jar, let me assume you are on ubuntu

install maven first
    sudo apt-get install maven

Then follow the instruction in /java/README.txt

If you want the standard jar

```
mvn package
```

If you want the lite version

```
mvn package -P lite
```

Then you can find the jar in /java/target

Comment: just comment: you should run maven inside java dir

Answer (score 5):

I am presuming you are on linux, Try going to the java directory, there is a **readme** file telling you how to create the jar with / without maven. You will have to create the jar from the supplied sources.

The without maven instructions are:

1) Build the C++ code, or obtain a binary distribution of protoc.  If
   you install a binary distribution, make sure that it is the same
   version as this package.  If in doubt, run:

```
 $ protoc --version
```

If you built the C++ code without installing, the compiler binary
   should be located in ../src.

2) Invoke protoc to build DescriptorProtos.java:

```
 $ protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src \
     ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
```

3) Compile the code in src/main/java using whatever means you prefer.

4) Install the classes wherever you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

you can download this jar from here

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/

Answer (score 2):

Like all Maven projects, you can get the project jar by clicking "[DOWNLOAD (Bundle)](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.6.0/protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar)" from the [project site](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.6.0).

If you look at the URL scheme of the bundle link, you'll notice you can go [a directory higher](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.6.0/) to see all available files for that release, including a sources and javadoc jar.

Answer (score 2):

To create protobuf.jar file using protobuf java follow below steps:

1.Check installed protobuf version:

```
$protoc --version
```

2. Install Java and Maven , Check their version:

```
$mvn --version
$java -version
```

3. Generate the protobuf.jar file , go to /protobuf/java directory. Run the below commands,

```
$mvn test
$mvn install
$mvn package
```

Check /protobuf/java/core/target/ directory,The .jar will be placed in the "target" directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can download google's protobuf.jar from [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomgoogleprotobuf240jar.htm)

This page serves almost all the jars that you need for development. I downloaded and use it in project

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to download ".jar" file and exclude maven. then

Try it link
"https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.6.1/"

Should click this link.
"https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/"
then you look all version.